# Did I get +8 for an up-vote?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, up-votes

How is it possible to have a +8 reputation for an upvote? Is this a bug, or is it possible to give a partial up-vote? I verified, and there's 1 upvote and 0 downvotes, so somehow it must have treated the up-vote as 8 points.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just verified, you did indeed.

Comment: @Pekka it resolved itself when I did a reputation recalc.  Since there was an accept in the mix, and since the rep for the day was below 215, I don't think i hit the rep cap.

Comment: @MatthewRead but now that I did the recalc, it shows up as +10.  Why would it have shown up as +8 before that (looking back, there was no intervening change)

Answer (score 12):

You hit the rep cap for the day - congrats!

Comment: Indeed.. but see my answer please - have I found a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, for external viewer (like me) it shows you got 10 points:

[image: 10 rep screenshot]

As Geoff correctly said the real amount gained is 8 due to daily rep cap, so the display of 10 looks like a bug.

Comment: Did you read the comments on the question? After he did the recalc it showed as +10 for him too.

Comment: <blush>nope</blush> - so it's still not really explained why it initially showed just 8.

Comment: Well, if 8 was correct (the tag wiki edit counts towards the rep cap) that is what it should show (I've had upvotes show as less than 10 before due to downvotes or downvoting), and I don't know why it says 10 now.

Comment: Are you sure tag wiki edit approval  counts towards rep cap? From what I know, the cap limits only rep from upvotes.

Comment: No, I'm not sure ("if 8 was correct"). If it doesn't count, then it was definitely a bug or a result of some complex situation.